# What are some FREE hosting sites that allow you to upload HTML?

Tags: web-development, html

Are there any **legitimate** free hosting sites that will let you upload your own html instead of using their pre-built templates?

Requirements:

- Free
- Host your own HTML
- Does not insert ads or anything to the HTML

Note: 000webhost and freehosting are out; no support whatsoever, can't get files to upload, everything times out, there's nothing redeemable about either of them.

Comment: Most implementations of cPanel will look the same - it is the same software no matter which host you go to, just potentially different versions of it.

Comment: I take some of this back.  On freehosting I can get to their file manager, but I can't figure out how to forward my domain to them because I can't figure out the URL to forward it to.  000webhost times out no matter what I do, although it at least tells me the URL to forward to.  I don't think Weebly lets you upload html.  There's got to be **some** hosting site as reliable as Weebly that lets you upload html.  I just can't find one!

Comment: neq3.com? Try that and see if that works. Beware the ad's though. :P~ annoying if you ask me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [hosting](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/675/185), and not *software*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you want to upload HTML and how tech-savvy you are. Here are some options:

- [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/) - client-side only, no server-side scripts which it doesn't sound like you want/need. More information on using Github pages to host a website: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-github-pages-to-host-your-website
- [Paperplane](http://www.paperplane.io/) is an option if you don't need a custom domain (which are a paid option)
- [Heroku](http://heroku.com) is much more than just a static website host but this tutorial will help you host a static site there: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby
- [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com) public folders is another option - here is a tutorial for hosting a website on Dropbox: http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/host-websites-with-dropbox
- as is [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com) with this guide: https://chadthompson.me/2013/05/static-web-hosting-with-amazon-s3/

Comment: Thanks!  Just curious if you have any personal knowledge of any of these sites, and if you know how much of a hassle to use/how reliable they are?

Comment: @JohnnyBones I've personally used all of them other than Paperplane. It'd be helpful to hear how you want to be uploading HTML as none of these provide an FTP connection. Amazon S3/Dropbox will likely be most user friendly.

Comment: @JohnnyBones note I added a new resource link to the Dropbox bullet point

Comment: I just need a place to put a small static html site (maybe 4 pages?) until I can rebuild my old webserver.  My HD crashed and one of my friends asked me to help him and doesn't have money to pay a host (long story), so I told him I'd host it as soon as I got my server back up.  But in the meantime, I need a place to put it.

Comment: I would definitely go with S3 for a combination of resiliency/reliability and features.